# Nexus is serving wrong npm package urls

Tags: npm, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nexus3, group

I have sonatype nexus (configured as npm group of hosted repo and proxy repo) installed behind reverse proxy.

After last update to OSS 3.41.1-01 we have problems installing via npm install. For some reason url of the actual files (.tgz) are served with wrong url (its using internal ip and not selected domain). In actual json returned from repo tarball options has internal url instead of domain ([Image of json from the repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZjIX.png)).

As of now i can't found any reference to this kind of problem.

I know of only one hack solution with using rewriting url from upstream which I don't want be doing.

Answer (score 0):

The tarball location is set by the incoming host headers. It it not clear how your reverse proxy is being used but you should be able to confirm that the Host header value is being set in the proxy configuration.

Sonatype provide apache and nginx examples for a few different use cases here. https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/planning-your-implementation/run-behind-a-reverse-proxy